# Generation PDF with PHP including an expiration date

Tags: php, date, pdf, drm

I have to send some text-information from the webserver to the users. Unfortunately, this text have to be destroyed (which means access to the information should be deny) after 7 days. So one idea is to create an pdf with an "expiration date" inside, in order to get an file which is unable to open, after the 7. day. 
Is this possible with PHP?

But how to start?

I don't need an solution which is 100% safe. The responsibility will be transferred to the user, if he goes an forbidden way to safe, copy or manipulate this document. I hope to find a way, to make the content unreadable (even it is (only) the first impression). But it looks like, there will be no way.

Comment: Its not possible with pdf. well, its not possible at all, how will you prevent access after 7 days? lets say you create some program, how will prevent access to screenshots the users might make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the PDF is generated, it cannot be "destroyed". There's no support in PDF for "do not open after 7 days", and such support is ENTIRELY dependent on the pdf viewer app honoring it. Nothing says the user can't reset their system clock back to a date/time that would fall within the PDF's viewing limit anyways.

PDF's (in)security flags are limited to encrypting the document so it can't be edited, and some flags to SUGGEST to the pd viewer that printing, screen reading, or text scraping should be forbidden. But they're just SUGGESTIONS and the PDF viewer is free to interpret/ignore them any way it wants.

Ultimately, this security "system" would be useless and trivially bypassed. And since it's browser-based, there is absolutely nothing you can do to control the remote user's machine to prevent the data from being downloaded/cached/saved in some form.

Comment: >But they're just SUGGESTIONS and the PDF viewer is free to interpret/ignore  <- the users are only allowed to use certain PDF reader. So i could check, if they ignore those settings. So i need a way to disable screen-reading and printing after 7 days...by using PHP. Looks like an impossible challenge.

Comment: Exactly. The security settings available in the PDF standard are booleans: on/off. There's no "enable this after X days" support at all.

Answer (score 1):

Content expiration is really an impossible problem. You can create some page that will be cleared after 7 days, but can't prevent people to copy the content to some other place.

All existing 'solutions' to this problem depend on [Security through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Which means people won't be able to get around your 'security' because they don't know how it works, and not because it is secure by nature.

Comment: >You can create some page that will be cleared after 7 days <-- (see the update on my question) so how will i create an page which is cleared after 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the contents in a hidden form field. You can then add a JavaScript PDF action for the document open event so that the Javascript script will check the date and display the form field. This will work only if the end-user is using Adobe Reader. I am not sure whether there are other PDF viewer that support Adobe PDF Javascript.

This kind of security is a bit amateurish. As mentioned by another repsonder, the end-user can change the system date and the bypass the security measure.

If the JavaScript can obtain from a https webserver with a digital certificate, then perhaps this will work.

Comment: thats sound interesting. JavaScript over https is not possible, because the user only can receive mails.

Comment: To obtain the correct date, the JavaScript can be made to access a web page over https. As this measure can also be bypassed altering the DNS, the server should also have a certificate. All this looks very awkward. The user should try to keep things very simple and avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: Using the FDF feature, secret information can be imported from a webserver and then displayed inside a field. That way, changing the system time will not work. It however does not satisfy the original requirement of putting the secret information IN the document.